How to use local Bitcoin wallet with remote bitcoind node for transaction creation
I'm trying to manage a Bitcoin wallet on my local machine using bitcoin-cli, but my local node isn't and cannot be fully synced and can't be pruned due to the need for historical UTXO data to build transactions. I want to connect to a remote bitcoind node that has all the blockchain data but doesn't have my wallet.
My goal is to:

Use the local wallet (with private keys stored locally).
Connect to the remote bitcoind node for blockchain data.
Build and sign a PSBT transaction locally, using the UTXOs data about my local wallet, from the remote node.
Broadcast transactions via the remote node.

What I have tried:
bitcoin-cli -testnet -rpcconnect=remote.node.address -rpcport=8332 -wallet='my_local_wallet' getbalance
However, this doesn’t seem to work since bitcoin-cli expects the wallet and blockchain data to be on the same bitcoind instance.
Is there a way to achieve this setup, where I can keep my wallet local but utilize a remote node for the blockchain data? Any help or alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated!
